# Azure B2C Redirect after Login/Signup - Blazor

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor

I have a blazor app that is using B2C to authenticate to.  That part works fine, but what I need to do is when a user Signs Up I need to check to see if they are a new user and then seed a DB.  I was just thinking on using the Redirect URI so that after login/signup it forwards to a component that I can check the New User claim and go from there.  But no matter what I set the Redirect URI in Azure to, it just goes back to the app home page or to the login/redirect page if one was set. New to this so not sure if I'm even on the right path. Thanks!

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
   {
   var configuration = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConfiguration>();
   var authentication = options.ProviderOptions.Authentication;
   authentication.Authority = configuration["Authority"]; 
   authentication.ClientId = configuration["clientId"];
   authentication.PostLogoutRedirectUri = configuration["postLogoutUrl"];
   authentication.ValidateAuthority = false;
   });
```

```
{
  "Authority": "https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com/Logbooks.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signinup",
  "clientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "postLogoutUrl": "https://localhost:xxxxx"
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two events you can capture, the first one here sets up the redirect URL for *after* the token has been authenticated, which is optional.

The second event is where you'd talk to your services to make users, update claims, etc - using the just validated token.

```
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
            {
                context.Properties.RedirectUri = "YOUR LOCAL URI FOR AFTER LOGIN";
            };

            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                // Token was just validated, talk to your DB
                // to create users or add claims as needed using
                // context.principal
                // Example for adding claims below
                    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity) context.Principal.Identity;
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(type: ClaimTypes.Role, value: "foo"));
                }
            };

        });
```

Comment: Do you know what the equivalent is for a Blazor WASM app?

Answer (score 1):

Part of @StefanGordon's solution worked for me - in startup.cs. Change "/dashboard" with the url you want the user to go to after a successful login.

```
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
            OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
                {
                    context.Properties.RedirectUri = "/Dashboard;
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a line in your code:

```
authentication.navigateToLoginRequestUrl = false;
```

The default value of property `navigateToLoginRequestUrl` is `true`.

You can know more information about the property on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-initializing-client-applications).

Comment: Unfortunately that has not effect. Not sure if it has to do with me using .NET framework or not..